# why array variable is getting updated

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I wrote this code and a part of this is not written by me and I'm not able to understand how a function is updating my `arrayData`?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int *insert(int arr[], int size, int elem, int pos);

int main()
{
    // Create a array
    int arrayData[50] = {0};

    // Insert data
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        arrayData[i] = i + 1;
    }

    int elem = 40, pos = 5, size = 10;

    // insert the element
    insert(arrayData, size, elem, pos);

    // show the data
    for (int i = 0; i < size + 1; i++)
    {
        cout << arrayData[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}

int *insert(int arr[], int size, int elem, int pos)
{
    size++;

    // shift elements forward
    for (int i = size; i >= pos; i--)
        arr[i] = arr[i - 1];

    // insert x at pos
    arr[pos - 1] = elem;

    return arr;
}
```

OUTPUT:
`1 2 3 4 40 5 6 7 8 9 10`

Comment: Please be more specific. What in particular do you not understand? `arrayData` is passed to `insert` as `arr` and written to with the index notation.

Comment: What exactly is the question? The code for `insert` shows that it inserts a new element in a given position of the array, which is what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is updating it because you are giving the function the memory address of the array (`int arr[]`), so the array is not copied into the function like other variables are.

Comment: Don't we use `*` for them?

Comment: like `int *arr[]`?

Comment: @R.Gurung `*` is the same as `[]`, but for arrays people usually use `[]` so the reader can see that it's an array.